# poor translations / translations with an agenda

Tags: discussion, sources-and-citations

the quality of original/translated citations is something we should be concerned about to improve the overall quality of the site.

issues:

(1) no citations

(2) Alleged citations with no clickable link or publisher information

(3) translations tripped up by the colossal ambiguity of Sanskrit and poor knowledge of Sanskrit by the translator

(4) agenda-driven translations (this topic is a third rail at this site)

So providing originals would ENORMOUSLY improve the quality and credibility of this site.